# How to make an input to search from database based on select option in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, search, sqlite3-ruby

So I have a form where in an input (type: text) and a select option one next to each other. I want to be able when choosing an option from the select option (either "search from your food" or "search food") to search from the corresponding table in the database.
For example: You choose from the select option "search from your food" so in the text input you query the "user_food" table. If you choose "search food" you query the "food" table.
Oh, by the way I use Sqlite3 as a database (the standard for Rails).

This is how the input looks so far:

[image]

And this is the code for it:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<%= select_tag :food_selection, options_for_select([['Search for food', 'foods'], ['Search your food', 'user_foods']]) %>
```

Controller

```
if params[:selection] == 'foods'
  @foods = Food.where('...')
else
  @foods = UserFood.where('...')
end

@foods = @foods.limit(20) # chain methods here they both share
```

Comment: Great! Will this work only when submitting the form? Is there a way to search it without submitting the form, because there are multiple inputs like these and I need to be able to select an item before submitting the form.

Comment: So do you mean like an AJAX request in the background?

Comment: Yeah something like that.

Comment: Ah, that's javascript then. Look at jQuery and `$.ajax`